# How do I bundle Filter gem dependencies mentioned in html-pipeline post-install message?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, bundler, github-pages

I'm following [GitHub's guide for using Jekyll with GitHub Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages/). When I run 'bundle install', the following message appears afterwards:

```
Post-install message from html-pipeline:
-------------------------------------------------
Thank you for installing html-pipeline!
You must bundle Filter gem dependencies.
See html-pipeline README.md for more details.
https://github.com/jch/html-pipeline#dependencies
-------------------------------------------------
```

I don't quite understand [the instructions in the html-pipeline's README.md](https://github.com/jch/html-pipeline/tree/89ceeadf7c7c044636773d89bc54a6ce1143456e#dependencies). What exactly does all this mean, and what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

The [README](https://github.com/jch/html-pipeline/tree/89ceeadf7c7c044636773d89bc54a6ce1143456e#dependencies) you provided states that in order to utilize the various filter functionality within html-pipeline, you must include additional libraries.

The example given in the docs:

> `SyntaxHighlightFilter` uses `github-linguist` to detect and highlight languages. For example, to use the SyntaxHighlightFilter, add the following to your Gemfile:
>
> ```
> gem 'github-linguist'
> ```

You essentially add the required gem(s) corresponding to the filter you wish to have available. Once added to the Gemfile, you can run `bundle install` and you should be good to go.

I know this practically echoed the docs you provided, but I hope it helps.